# Poor Write I/O Performance on HP ML110 G9 Server With ESXi 6.0U2

Tags: virtualization, performance, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012-r2, io

hi everyone i need a little bit of help since i cant find a solution,

i have a HP ML110 G9 Server with:
8gb Ram
2 HDD of 2tb Each one and one SSD of 250 GB

i have installed ESXi 6.0u2 HP Customized.

and a Windows Server 2012 R2 in it. 
using VMWare Paravirtual Controller

i have deactivated the B120i Controller because the I/O where Horrible.
and it didnt have Write Cache so i thought that was the problem.

sorry. i made a small mistake the controller is a B140i

The windows is installed on one of the 2tb HDD

here is a picture of the diferent result of atto benchmark:

[Atto Benchmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEjoe.jpg)

so, i dont know what can i do to improve the performance.
any help is greatly appreciated!!!!!!!!
and sorry if my english isnt very good. i try my best.

Comment: You only have 8GB of memory on an ESXi server?!?! and HPE don't make a 250GB SSD for that server - why would you have so little memory and unsupported disks in a production server?

Comment: What write performance were you expecting? Those graphs look about right for what you have.

Comment: we are planning upgrades for the server but we are a small company with a small budget. so we have to make things work with what we have.

Comment: i expected better performance at 16kb or less, i belive that is what make our internal development go slow.

Answer (score 3):

You need write cache for a server like this. Otherwise, your performance will be throttled by the low I/O capabilities of the 7200 RPM disks you're using.

Your best option is to reenable your Smart Array controller and add a write cache to it. See part #676473-B21

Also see: http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04168333.pdf

Comment: Thanks!, while i was checking this information i realized that the controller was a B140i with no memory capabilities.
http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04390743.pdf

Comment: what would you recommend to increase the write performance of this system?

Comment: Get a FBWC module for write caching.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the driver and the controller disabling the hd drive write cache.
You can try using windows hyper-v, and will see the real performance.
Sadly HP doesn't make a decent driver for vmware neither linux.
Bad move from HP.